# Xcode 7 build failed: ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, target, google-analytics-sdk

Every time when I open my app with Xcode I get this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Then I need to unmark the target on the `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a` file and mark it on again. After the uncheck/check of the target the app runs normally...

[image]

I get 2 other warning when this happens:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vision/Documents/Apps/Mijn Cijfers/Mijn'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LCijfers'
```

Now this looks like Xcode can't read spaces and looks for a new directory called Cijfers. My app is called: Mijn Cijfers, but I never had this problem before with spaces in my project name.

Every time when I check/uncheck the target of `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a` the Library Search Path is adding new rows:

[image]

I think both cases has to do something with the warnings and errors that I get. It's really annoying to remove the Library Search Paths and check/uncheck the target to let my app run normally. -.-

Does anyone know a solution to solve this odd bug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to delete all these path except the "$inherited" and then add Google Analytics library path (Drag the folder where you saved the library).

If you follow this then you don't need to recheck/uncheck the library path.

[image: library search Path screen shot]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made a new folder called: "Library" with Finder in the Project root folder (with the Google Analytics SDK files) and than drag the folder to the Library Search Path window. If I close Xcode now and re-open I can finally build my app! :D

Comment: i am getting same error (linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)) but it is saying library not found for -libc++, how to resolve this

Answer (score 11):

If you have just created pod file by running $ **`pod init`** command in terminal,

- then just close project and Open `projectName.xcworkspace` instead of `projectName.xcodeproj`

which will not throw error -lxyzLibray eg. -lJSONModel not found.

Now compile and debug again It will work.

Comment: This works. But when I compile and upload it to itunes connect, do I use `projectName.xcodeproj` or `projectName.xcworkspace` from Xcode?