# Xcode product archive error

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, flutter

When I try to archive my project with Xcode I've got an error:

```
ld: library not found for -lReachability
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code  1
```

Can you help me how to fix that?

Comment: Missing any pods in the podfile?

Comment: @Hamed how to add all pods?

Comment: Are you working on workspace right? Please open your podfile and verify all your pods are there. After that install the pods via terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the path that Xcode use to find your **Reachability** framework.

Create your search path like this

> $(PROJECT_DIR)/../yourFramework/lib

and add it in **Build Settings-> Framework Search Paths** for both debug and release builds.

You can get the exact path from Finder get info.

Check the reference links

1. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358591/xcode-library-not-found?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
2. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220272/xcode-7-build-failed-ld-library-not-found-for-lgoogleanalyticsservices/33221787)